# Shells Script to execute mqtt command

Tags: shell, mqtt

Want to some of the MQTT AT command from script.

```
#!system/bin/sh

#Open the Network
echo -e "AT+CMQTTSTART"

#Acquire a Clienr
echo -e "AT+CMQTTACCQ=0,"client c" "

#set the will topic
echo -e "AT+CMQTTWILLTOPIC=0,10" 

#set the will message 
echo -e "AT+CMQTTWILLMSG=0,56,1"

#connect to the Server
echo -e "AT+CMQTTCONNECT=0,"tcp://192.168.9.27:5141",20,1,”2208e”,"Adff0c=-_""

#Send subscribe message to server
echo -e "AT+CMQTTSUB=0,9,1,1" 

#Send un subscribe message to server 
echo -e "AT+CMQTTUNSUB=0,9,1" 

#Disconnect from the Server 
echo -e "AT+CMQTTDISC=0,60"

#Release Client
echo -e "AT+CMQTTREL=0" 

#Close the Network
echo -e "AT+CMQTTSTOP"
```

I don't this AT command executed or not. but, I got the print of every AT Commands

Comment: that is all `echo` is supposed to do. You need to setup a program to receive that output. Something like `./yourScriptAbove.sh | mqtt` ? But best if you read a tutorial on and get the most simple thing to work first, then start adding features. Good luck.

Comment: There is also no response checking, so this will just carry on even if there is an error

Answer (score -1):

#!system/bin/sh

#Open the Network

echo -e "AT+CMQTTSTART" > /dev/ttyUSB1

#Acquire a Client

echo -e "AT+CMQTTACCQ=0,"client c" "  > /dev/ttyUSB1

#set the will topic

echo -e "AT+CMQTTWILLTOPIC=0,10"  > /dev/ttyUSB1

#set the will message

echo -e "AT+CMQTTWILLMSG=0,56,1" > /dev/ttyUSB1

#connect to the Server

echo -e "AT+CMQTTCONNECT=0,"tcp://192.168.9.27:5141",20,1,”2208e”,"Adff0c=-_""  > /dev/ttyUSB1

#Send subscribe message to server

echo -e "AT+CMQTTSUB=0,9,1,1"   > /dev/ttyUSB1

#Send un subscribe message to server

echo -e "AT+CMQTTUNSUB=0,9,1"  > /dev/ttyUSB1

#Disconnect from the Server

echo -e "AT+CMQTTDISC=0,60"  > /dev/ttyUSB1

#Release Client

echo -e "AT+CMQTTREL=0"  > /dev/ttyUSB1

#Close the Network

echo -e "AT+CMQTTSTOP"  > /dev/ttyUSB1